# Changing default choice in grub dialog

Tags: grub2

I just upgraded kernel and the dialog became like this:

[image]

There's only one kernel and I want to select the first entry "Ubuntu" by default, how should I do that?

Comment: Can you not just scroll up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the GRUB_DEFAULT=0 in /etc/default/grub file. and then run the update-grub command.